# How do I call a servlet/portlet outside the LIFERAY container?

Tags: jsp, liferay

I have a requirement to execute a call outside a LIFERAY container running in TOMCAT. The call must be via HTTPS straight into a server completely different than the one hosting LIFERAY. This outside server shall return a couple of values to be shown in the LIFERAY portlet that triggered the call.

Comment: So, what did you try? Did you try opening a URL connection to this external URL?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Prior to posting this question I conceived (had a rough sketch) a solution calling for the construction of a Liferay portlet talking to a an outside servlet hosted on a separate server, communicating over HTTPS. I decided to post the question to see whether anyone had come up with anything more specific and / or practical. I'm half way thru the implementation or my design.

Answer (score 0):

I see no problem at all in issuing an HTTPS request from a portlet to some external site. Using a simple library like [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) will do the trick?